# how to make conditional proxy redirect with hapijs?

Tags: node.js, reverse-proxy, hapi.js

I have the following route code:

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: {
    file: './public/index.html'
  }
});
server.route({
  method: '*',
  path: '/gms/{f*}',
  handler: {
    proxy: {
      mapUri: function(request, callback){
        var resourceUri, url;
        resourceUri = request.url.path.replace('/gms/', '/');
        url = 'http://example.com:81/' + resourceUri;
        console.log('url: ', url);
        return callback(null, url);
      },
      passThrough: true,
      xforward: true
    }
  }
});
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/{f*}',
  handler: {
    directory: {
      path: 'public',
      listing: 'true',
      index: ['index.html']
    }
  }
});
```

I'm expecting hapi to redirect `/foo/bar` request to `public` directory, as `./public/foo/bar`; but proxy `/gms/foo/bar` from `http://example.com:81/foo/bar`.

If I delete either second or third route, remaining declarations work as expected.

How can I make these both work?

Comment: You'll probably get a faster response if you showed JS rather than CS. The majority of the Node/hapi community does not use CS.

Comment: 100x yes. Questions with Coffeescript samples often languish on here without a response for a long time. Make it as easy as possible for people to help you and they'll appreciate it.

Comment: You have point. I've compiled the code to javascript.